# .net core project and npm configuration

Tags: npm, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on .Net core 2.0 project that uses razor views as client side.

I have added npm configuration file and in it I have added bootstrap package, after installing npm in root folder, I get node_modules for bootstrap.

Now, **the issues is that how to use that files in my _layout.cshtml page or in other views.**

1. I have read somewhere that after initializing project, **it will automatically generates all css in wwwroot folder**, In my case it's not.
2. I tried to access node_modules directly, see below. but i's also not working.

   ```
   <link href="~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
   ```

see the snap of error.

[image]

> can anyone help me and suggest me that what is the proper way to include external css files in .net core 2.0 prrject. thanks!